# Ember Component Functions

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

Trying to call one of my ember components functions, however I am getting the error:
`e-signature.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: this.testFunc is not a function`

I have clearly declared the function, however.  I am calling `testFunc()` when the user presses their mouse (which is when the error is thrown).  What is the issue?

### Component.js

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    mousePressed: false,
    lastX: 0,
    lastY: 0,
    ctx: null,

    Draw(x, y, isDown) {
        if (isDown) {
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = $('#selColor').val();
            this.ctx.lineWidth = $('#selWidth').val();
            this.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
            this.ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
            this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            this.ctx.closePath();
            this.ctx.stroke();
        }
        this.lastX = x; this.lastY = y;
    },

    InitThis() {
        this.ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
        console.log(this.ctx)

        $('#myCanvas').mousedown(function (e) {
            this.mousePressed = true;
            this.testFunc();
            this.Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, false);
        });

        $('#myCanvas').mousemove(function (e) {
            if (this.mousePressed) {
                this.Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
            }
        });

        $('#myCanvas').mouseup(function (e) {
            this.mousePressed = false;
        });
            $('#myCanvas').mouseleave(function (e) {
            this.mousePressed = false;
        });
    },

    testFunc: function() {
        console.log('testFunc');
    },

    didRender() {
        console.log('eSignature didRender()');
        this.InitThis();
    },

    actions: {
        clearArea() {
        // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
        this.ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.canvas.width, this.ctx.canvas.height);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try `this.get('testFunc')() ` for calling testFunc method. one more option you can move this to actions hash and call `this.send('testFunc')`

Comment: I get `this.get` and `this.send` are not functions

Comment: Oh sorry `this` context is wrong..other than that what you are doing is correct it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` context is wrong. I would suggest you to get component properties using `get` function

```
var _this = this;
$('#myCanvas').mousedown(function (e) {
            _this.set('mousePressed',true);
            _this.testFunc();
            _this.Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, false);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised the context changes as only the function scope is different